# How to use Selenium to click a button in a popup modal box

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, modal-dialog, click

I am trying to use Selenium in Python to pull some data from https://www.seekingalpha.com. The front page has a "Sign-in/Join now" link. I used Selenium to click it, which brought up a popup asking for sign-in information with another "Sign in" button. It seems my code below can enter my username and password, but my attempt to click the "sign in" button didn't get the right response (it clicked on the ad below the popup box.)

I am using Python 3.5.

Here is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = "https://seekingalpha.com"

driver.get(url)

sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="sign-in"]').click() 

sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="authentication_login_email"]').send_keys("xxxx@gmail.com") 

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="authentication_login_password"]').send_keys("xxxxxxxxx") 

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="log-btn"]').click()
```

Any advice/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: sending the enter key in the password field usually works...

Comment: Thank you pcalkins and Trapli. I followed your suggestions and tried both approaches (driver.execute_script or send the ENTER key to pw), but neither is working. I do noticed that even if I clicked the "Sign in" button manually in the browser brought up by 
driver.get("https://seekingalpha.com"), there was no response. However, if I opened seekingalpha.com in a Chrome browser manually, and manually brought up the authentication popup, then manually clicked the "sign in " button, it responded. Why is that? Do I need to somehow set the simulated control to the popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: previous 'answer' was wrong so I have updated it.

Got you man, this is what you need to do:
1.) grab the latest firefox
2.) grab the latest geckodriver
3.) use a firefox driver

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'd:\Python_projects\geckodriver.exe')

url = "https://seekingalpha.com"

driver.get(url)

sign_in = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="sign-in"]')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', sign_in)
time.sleep(1)

email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="authentication_login_email"]')
email.send_keys("xxxx@gmail.com")
pw = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="authentication_login_password"]')
pw.send_keys("xxxxxxxxx")
pw.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

**Explanation:**

It is easy to detect if selenium is used or not if the browser [tells that information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/webdriver) (and it seems this page does not want to be scraped):

> The webdriver read-only property of the navigator interface indicates whether the user agent is controlled by automation.

I have looked for an answer how to bypass detection and found [this](https://edmundmartin.com/detecting-selenium/) article.

> Your best of avoiding detection when using Selenium would require you to use one of the latest builds of Firefox which don’t appear to give off any obvious sign that you are using Firefox.

Gave a shot and after launch the correct page design loaded and the login attempt resulted the same like the manual attempt.

Also with a bit more searching found that [if you modify your chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52108199/8375783), you have a chance to bypass detection even with chromedriver.

Learned something new today too. \o/

**An additional idea:**

I have made a little experiment using embedded chromium (CEF). If you open a chrome window via selenium and you open the console and check `navigator.webdriver` the result will be `True`. If you open a CEF window however and then remote debug it, the flag will be `False`. I did not check edge cases with it but non-edge-case scenarios should be fine with CEF.

So what you may want to check out in the future:

1.) in command line: `pip install cefpython3`
2.) `git clone https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython.git`
3.) open your CEF project and find `hello.py`in the examples
4.) update the startup to `cef.Initialize(settings={"remote_debugging_port":9222})`
5.) run `hello.py`
(this was the initial, one time setup, you may customize it in the future, but the main thing is done, you have a browser with a debug port open)
6.) modify chrome startup to:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.debugger_address = "127.0.0.1:9222"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=chrome_driver_executable)
```

7.) now you have a driver without 'automated' signature in the browser. There may be some drawbacks like:

- CEF is not super very latest, right now the latest released chrome is v76, CEF is v66.
- also "some stuff" may not work, like `window.Notification` is not a thing in CEF

Comment: Thank you pcalkins and Trapli. I followed your suggestions and tried both approaches (driver.execute_script or send the ENTER key to pw), but neither is working. I do noticed that even if I clicked the "Sign in" button manually in the browser brought up by driver.get("seekingalpha.com"), there was no response. However, if I opened seekingalpha.com in a Chrome browser manually, and manually brought up the authentication popup, then manually clicked the "sign in " button, it responded. Why is that? Do I need to somehow set the simulated control to the popup?

Comment: @Trapli Thank you very much!!! This works beautifully. And it is much more straightforward than to modify the chromedriver.

Comment: @Trapli, what is the options() in the line "chrome_options = Options()"? Thanks.

Comment: @BinChen `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options`

Comment: added to answer too

Answer (score 2):

I tried code you provided and it works fine. i added selenium wait just to check other options and those also worked well i changed 2 lines instead of `sleeps`

```
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
signin = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id ='sign-in']")))
#sleep(5)

signin.click()

#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="sign-in"]').click()

#sleep(5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id ='authentication_login_email']")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="authentication_login_email"]').send_keys("xxxx@gmail.com")
```

and it does click on `Sign in` button. and what i found is there is captcha handling on the site when i checked console after clicked on sign in button it tell the story. I went ahead and added user agent to your script but it did not worked as well. Notice the blockscript parameter in response of login API and console errors in below screenshots. However there is no captcha on the ui - 
[image: console error]

[image: api error]

Comment: Each and every aspect mentioned in the answer is just perfect. Though the blocking issue still not conclusive to me.

Comment: @DebanjanB when script clicks on the sign in button no error message on ui and it shows no change

Comment: Correct, I am not sure why Chrome is complaining _...resource interpreted as document but transferred with mime type image/gif..._, still clueless.

Comment: @dev thanks for pointing out that I was totally misinterpreted the problem. After checking the page a bit more thoroughly, even the page design is different depending on how it was opened.

Comment: I think I have an answer for the problem. I have updated my original answer.

Comment: @dev Thank you for diagnosing the cause. Great finding!