# When using selenium to log in to Instagram, the error "incorrect password" is displayed

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, instagram

I wrote the following code to log in to Instagram, but I get an error that I'm entering the wrong password. Although it is correct. In general, in the chrome window from the driver, I can't log in to insta, not even through the script.

The code I use is below. I tried a lot of different variants of using stealth. But the results are the same. When I log in from a simple login window, everything is fine.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium_stealth import stealth
import random

username = '***'
password = '***'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
# options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

stealth(driver,
        user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        languages=["uk-UA", "uk"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
        )

try:
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')

    # Wait for the username input field to be clickable with an increased wait time
    username_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'username'))
    )

    username_input.clear()
    time.sleep(5)
    username_input.send_keys(username)

    # Wait for the password input field to be clickable
    password_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'password'))
    )

    password_input.clear()
    time.sleep(4)
    password_input.send_keys(password)
    time.sleep(1)
    password_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

#     Add a wait for some element on the next page if needed
#     WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
#         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 'your_xpath_here'))
#     )

except NoSuchElementException as e:
    print(f"Element not found: {e}")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

finally:
    # Ensure that the entire browser window is closed
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You must use another web browser that does not tell you the page you visit is automated. There's this thread as a reference (Trapli's answer): [How to use Selenium to click a button in a popup modal box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57777773/how-to-use-selenium-to-click-a-button-in-a-popup-modal-box/57778034#57778034)